# Jupyter not recognizing packages that I have installed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, datagrid, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Lab and am having trouble figuring out why DataGrid displays are not working. When I run

```
import pandas as pd
from ipydatagrid import DataGrid

df = pd.DataFrame({
            "column 1": [{"key": 11}, ["berry", "apple", "cherry"]],
            "column 2": [["berry", "berry", "cherry"], {"key": 10}]})
DataGrid(df)
```

I get the following output instead of the graphical display I would expect:

```
DataGrid(auto_fit_params={'area': 'all', 'padding': 30, 'numCols': None}, corner_renderer=None, default_render…
```

When I run `!jupyter --version` in my notebook I get the following:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.16.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.5
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

However when I search for the three uninstalled packages individually and import them it works:

```
import ipywidgets
import qtconsole
import jupyterlab
print("ipywidgets: " + ipywidgets.__version__)
print("qtconsole: " + qtconsole.__version__)
print("jupyterlab: " + jupyterlab.__version__)
```

gives:

```
ipywidgets: 8.0.7
qtconsole: 5.4.3
jupyterlab: 3.6.5
```

What exactly is going on here and how do I get Jupyter to properly recognize these packages in the `!jupyter --version` command? I have uninstalled and reinstalled these packages, restarted my Python kernel, restarted my computer, etc. several times and have double checked that these packages do exist in my site-packages folder (and that my venv is pointing to the correct site-packages folder). I am using pip and not anaconda in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Try running jupyter via `python -m jupyter notebook` with your venv activated

Comment: @C.Nivs that worked and the DataGrid is displaying correctly in that environment. Any idea how I can get my other environment to properly display the grid now that you know what the problem is? Do I need to run some kind of .show() or something? I suspect the package needs to configure notebook or lab display properly

Comment: Tip: when checking versions installed from inside your notebook, use `%pip list`. That will give you information related to the environment your kernel is running in. Because of the way the exclamation command, sometimes it will give information about a general shell environment, which may be misleading as that is not where your kernel backing your notebook is running. See the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for one idea on why. Related: use `%pip install` in a notebook, too.

Comment: @Wayne thanks. I have checked using ```%pip list``` and all relevant libraries are installed properly in my environment

Comment: But it still isn't displaying correctly there?

Comment: Correct, it's still not displaying